# How can I sort a list of numbers, by its last 3 digits in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a list of numbers in the first column (that is: I have a number in A_1,A_2,...).

Each one of the nubers if have 8-9 digits and I would like to sort this column by its last 3 digits (or create another column with the numbers sorted) (I would like that the last 3 digits of A_1 will be smaller or equal to those of A_2 etc')

Does anyone know of a way to do such a task ?

Note: I have Office 2010 installed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is VBA out of the question?

Comment: @djerry - what is VBA ?

Comment: basically, VBA can solve your problem without having to add additional columns/data to your sheet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on xl2007 (but I doubt differs for Office 2010):

In `B1` enter `=RIGHT(A1,3)` and copy down as required.
Copy ColumnB and Paste  / Special / Values over the top.
Sort ColumnA:B AZ with Sort by ColumnB.

Comment: +1, I double checked in XL2010 and it works fine.